Tabs o dots no redirigen a la seccion al dar click next js
Las tabs no redirigen bien a la seccion al dar click, a veces funciona y otras veces no, soy nuevo en gsap y next js, primero itero las secciones despues itero las tabs y por ultimo las conecto, no se si esta bien la logica, como podria solucionar ese error?
link codepen ejemplo


gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger, ScrollToPlugin);

let panels = gsap.utils.toArray(".panel");
    let scrollTween;

    function goToSection(i) {
      scrollTween = gsap.to(window, {
        scrollTo: {
          y: i * innerHeight,
          autoKill: false,
          ease: "Power3.easeInOut",
        },
        duration: 1.5,
        onComplete: () => (scrollTween = null),
        overwrite: true,
      });
    }

    panels.forEach((panel, i) => {
      const tl = gsap.timeline({ paused: true, reversed: true });
      const tlreverse = gsap.timeline({ paused: true, reversed: true });

      tl.to(panel.querySelector(".parr1"), { xPercent: 0, opacity: 1 }).to(
        panel.querySelector(".parr2"),
        { xPercent: 0, opacity: 1 },
        "<"
      );

      tlreverse
        .to(panel.querySelector(".parr1"), { xPercent: -50, opacity: 0 })
        .to(panel.querySelector(".parr2"), { xPercent: 50, opacity: 0 }, "<");

      ScrollTrigger.create({
        trigger: panel,
        onToggle: (self) => self.isActive && !scrollTween && goToSection(i),
      });

      ScrollTrigger.create({
        trigger: panel,
        start: "bottom bottom",
        onEnterBack: () => goToSection(i),
      });

      ScrollTrigger.create({
        animation: tl,
        trigger: panel,
        start: "top bottom",
        end: "top top",
        scrub: 1,
        /* markers: true, */
      });

      ScrollTrigger.create({
        animation: tlreverse,
        trigger: panel,
        start: "bottom bottom",
        end: "bottom top",
        scrub: 1,
      });
    });




    let links = gsap.utils.toArray("nav a");
    links.forEach((a, i) => {
      let element = document.querySelector(a.getAttribute("href")),

      linkST = ScrollTrigger.create({
        trigger: element,
        start: "top top",
      });

      ScrollTrigger.create({
        trigger: element,
        start: "top center",
        end: "bottom center",
        onToggle: (self) => self.isActive && setActive(a),
      });

      a.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        gsap.to(window, {
          duration: 1.5,
          scrollTo: linkST.start,
          overwrite: "auto",
        });
      });
    });

    function setActive(link) {
      links.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("active"));
      link.classList.add("active");
    }
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parr1{
  translate: 0 -50;
}

.parr2{
  translate: 0 50;
}

.panel p {
  font-size: 6vw;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: #0000007d;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
nav a {
  line-height: 1.7;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--color-surface-white);
  opacity: 0.6;
}
nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

nav a.active {
  opacity: 1
}
<div class="content">
      <section id="one" class="panel red">
        <p class="parr1">This is page 1</p>
        <p class="parr2">h1 1</p>
      </section>
      <section id="two" class="panel green">
        <p class="parr1">This is page 2</p>
        <p class="parr2">h2 2</p>
      </section>
      <section id="three" class="panel blue">
        <p class="parr1">This is page 3</p>
        <p class="parr2">h3 3</p>
      </section>
      <section id="four" class="panel orange">
        <p class="parr1">This is page 4</p>
        <p class="parr2">h4 4</p>
      </section>

      <nav>
        <div>
          <a href="#one">Section one</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#two">Section two</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#three">Section three</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#four">Section four</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>




Claramente hay un error de lógica de procedimiento. Primero, el problema está al ir desde la sección uno a la 4ta por ejemplo, simplemente se detiene en la siguiente. Pero esto no ocurre cuando es al revés... de todos modos, si voy desde la 4ta a la 1ra, no debería demorarse tanto ni detenerse en las otras 2 secciones no ?

La traducción de la explicación en inglés está de más. Acá hablamos la lengua de cervantes. Está [so] en inglés, dónde podrías publicar tu pregunta en ese idioma, pero los sitios son independientes y no suelen considerarse bilingües.
